# code compiles on Sun Studio but gives error on gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I have this code which gets compiles using Sun Studio but gives error in g++

```
DBManager & DBManager::operator >> (UtlString &value)
{
  //## begin DBManager::operator>>%921890065.body preserve=yes
        if(_state == DBMRan){
                _reader >> static_cast<std::string>(value);
        }
        return *this;
  //## end DBManager::operator>>%921890065.body
}

DBManager.cpp:263: error: no match for âoperator>>â in â((DBManager*)this)->DBManager::_reader >> std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)(&((jda::UtlString*)value)->jda::UtlString::<anonymous>))))â
DBReader.h:50: note: candidates are: virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(char&)
DBReader.h:51: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(unsigned char&)
DBReader.h:52: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(short int&)
DBReader.h:53: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(short unsigned int&)
DBReader.h:54: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(int&)
DBReader.h:55: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(unsigned int&)
DBReader.h:56: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(long int&)
DBReader.h:57: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(long long int&)
DBReader.h:58: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(long unsigned int&)
DBReader.h:59: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(long long unsigned int&)
DBReader.h:60: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(float&)
DBReader.h:61: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(double&)
DBReader.h:62: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(DBDateTime&)
DBReader.h:63: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(DBBlob&)
DBReader.h:64: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(std::string&)
DBReader.h:65: note:                 virtual DBReader& DBReader::operator>>(DBNullIndicator&)
otlv4.h:35416: note:                 otl_connect& operator>>(otl_connect&, otl_stream&)
```

As you can see in above error message that DBReader class has operator>> which takes std::string by reference and UtlString class is derived from std::string so static_cast should not be a problem but still compiler complains that there is no matching method. 
Also can anyone  tell me   how to remove â charachter appearing in error message.

Thanks

Comment: I think, `â` is how your console displays `'` for some reason... And shouldn't you cast it to `std::string &`?

Comment: I changes static_cast<std::string> to static_cast<std::string&> but still same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build an temporary std::string from the UtlString.

```
std::string tmp(value);    
if(_state == DBMRan){    
    _reader >> tmp;    
}
```

That should at least work on both compilers.